# Drop lowest numeric value

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been stuck on this dplyr manipulation issue for a while now.

Here is a small sample size of my data:  `dput(test)`

```
structure(list(anon_screen_name = c("40492fd6e817cc25cea942be9eae7c1c5795ffa1", 
"862329793fdbcd666d660d9a9d2e3beceb07a0db", "862329793fdbcd666d660d9a9d2e3beceb07a0db", 
"862329793fdbcd666d660d9a9d2e3beceb07a0db", "862329793fdbcd666d660d9a9d2e3beceb07a0db", 
"862329793fdbcd666d660d9a9d2e3beceb07a0db", "862329793fdbcd666d660d9a9d2e3beceb07a0db", 
"862329793fdbcd666d660d9a9d2e3beceb07a0db", "a9c8719499b9ef73c78e85bada231591d807a821", 
"a9c8719499b9ef73c78e85bada231591d807a821"), resource_display_name = c("Quiz", 
"Quiz", "Quiz", "Quiz", "Quiz", "homework", "homework", "final_exam", 
"Quiz", "Quiz"), grade = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L), max_grade = c(2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
    percent_grade = c("0", "0", "\\N", "100", "100", "0", "9.09", 
    "100", "100", "100")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Basically, for each `anon_screen_name`, I want to drop the lowest `percent_grade` for the homework (in `resource_display_name`).

I started to write this starter code:

```
test %>% 
     mutate(percent_grade = as.numeric(percent_grade)) %>% 
     group_by(resource_display_name) %>% 
     summarise(min_percent_grade = min(percent_grade, na.rm = T))
```

But this only shows me the minimum homework grade *without taking out the row with the minimum homework grade*

**UPDATE:**

Basically, borrowing from a comment below, I want to remove the row(s) associated with the lowest value of `percent_grade` where resource_display_name == 'homework'

Comment: If several rows are equal to the minimum do you want to take them all out?

Comment: It's not clear to me what behavior you want. Do you only want to remove the row(s) associated with the lowest value of `percent_grade` where `resource_display_name == 'homework'`, or do you want to remove rows for the lowest value for each of the types of `resource_display_name`? Perhaps you could update the post with an illustration of the desired output.

Comment: @ulfelder 

I only want to remove the row(s) associated with the lowest value of percent_grade where resource_display_name == 'homework'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following codes:

```
test %>% 
  mutate(percent_grade = as.numeric(percent_grade)) %>% 
  filter(resource_display_name == 'homework') %>% 
  filter(percent_grade > min(percent_grade, na.rm = T)) -> t1


test %>% 
  mutate(percent_grade = as.numeric(percent_grade)) %>% 
  filter(resource_display_name != 'homework') -> t2

rbind(t1,t2)
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted. I want to remove the row(s) associated with the lowest value of percent_grade where resource_display_name == 'homework'

Answer (score 0):

The following will remove all values equal to the minimum per group of `resource_display_name`. Note that it's a base R solution, there is no need for an external package such as `dplyr`.

```
inx <- with(test, ave(as.numeric(percent_grade), resource_display_name, FUN = function(x) x != min(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
inx <- which(as.logical(inx))

test[inx, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove a **single** record, and not all records with the lowest grade, you could do something like the following.

```
test %>%
    mutate(percent_grade = as.numeric(percent_grade)) %>%
    group_by(anon_screen_name) %>%
    mutate(lowest_grade = 1 * ((percent_grade == min(percent_grade, na.rm=TRUE)) & (resource_display_name == 'homework'))) %>%
    arrange(lowest_grade) %>%
    filter(row_number() != n()) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Comment: To remove **all** rows where `percent_grade == min(percent_grade)`, change the `filter` line to `filter(lowest_grade == 0)`.